# Deploying CAR to ESB using maven

Tags: maven, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to deploy a CAR file to a ESB instance. I am following the instructions here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS370/Deploying+a+CAR+File+with+the+Maven+Plug-In

But when I run the command:

```
 mvn clean deploy -Dmaven.car.deploy.skip=false
```

I get an error that many other people get.

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to configure plugin parameters for: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.4

check that the following section of the pom.xml is present and correct:

<distributionManagement>
  <!-- use the following if you're not using a snapshot version. -->
<repository>
<id>repo</id>
<name>Repository Name</name>
<url>scp://host/path/to/repo</url>
</repository>
<!-- use the following if you ARE using a snapshot version. -->
<snapshotRepository>
<id>repo</id>
<name>Repository Name</name>
<url>scp://host/path/to/repo</url>
</snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

Cause: Class 'org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository' cannot be instantiated
```

I don't want to deploy it to a repository, unless I am understanding this wrong.
I created a Maven Multi Module Project to package up the Java Mediator, the ESB Config Project and the Composite Application Project.

Why is this failing?

What is the correct way to deploy a car manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deploy a car file 'manually' you can simply execute a "mvn clean install" and copy the .car file from the target directory and copy to <CARBON_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps which hot-deploys the carbon app to ESB server.